# Scrabble code in java

Tags: java, scrabble

I have to write a scrabble code in java without the use of if/switch statements. this is what i have so far

```
public class Scrabble {


public static void main(String[] args) {
}

    public static int computeScore(String word) {

String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int[] values = {1,3,3,2,1,4,2,4,1,8,5,1,3,1,3,3,10,1,1,1,1,4,4,8,4,10};
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <word.length();i++) {
        ????

    }
return sum;

}

}
```

I need some help, I had the idea of finding the character inside the string and finding its value but not sure how to write it out. Any help will be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inside you for loop you would need to do the following:

```
sum += values[aplphabet.indexOf(word.charAt(i))];
```

So your loop should so something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i <word.length();i++) {
    sum += values[aplphabet.indexOf(word.charAt(i))];
}
```

This will of course not handle any modifier tiles on the scrabble board.

Alternatively you can use a `HashMap<char, int>` to store your letters, so that accessing them is a bit easier:

```
public class Scrabble {

    HashMap<char, int> alphabet;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //initialize the alphabet and store all the values
        alphabet = new HashMap<char, int>();
        alpahbet.put('A', 1);
        alpahbet.put('B', 3);
        alpahbet.put('C', 3);
        //...
        alpahbet.put('Z', 10);
    }

    public static int computeScore(String word) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i <word.length();i++) {
            //look up the current char in the alphabet and add it's value to sum
            sum += alphabet.get(word.charAt(i));
        }
        return sum;

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! now my only concern is that this only applies if the letters are UPPER CASE, i get an index out of bounds exception when I try to put in a word with lower case. Is there any way to fix this? was thinking toLowerCase method

Comment: @KennyHuynh the easiest way without modifying your code would be to add this line to your `computeScore` function above the loop: `word = word.toUpperCase();`  This will force the strings all to be uppercase.

Comment: ahh I get it, forcing the word to be all upper case will make it fine. Thank you so much!!!